# Multiprocessing pool map doesn't accept several arguments as list of lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How can I pass several argument to a pool.map correctly.
Currently I have an error saying :

```
File "C:/Users/maxime/Desktop/execom/di.py", line 42, in <module>
    A = pool.map(energy2, args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: energy2() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'window' and 'i'
```

zip doesn't work neither. 
I also try something with partial but if all arguments need to be defferent in each process, it is then pointless.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial
from itertools import repeat
import itertools


def energy2(signal, window,i ):
    L2 = int(len(window ) /2)
    Lw = len(window)
    taille = len(signal)
    channel_buffer = np.zeros(len(signal))
    filtered_signalI = np.hstack((np.zeros(L2) ,signal ,np.zeros(len(window))))
    for k in range(0 ,taille):
        buffer = (filtered_signalI[k : k + Lw ] * window)
        channel_buffer[k] = np.sqrt(np.sum(buffer * buffer))
    return channel_buffer / Lw



if __name__=="__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    # serial
    window = np.random.rand(32)
    N = 10
    Signals = np.zeros((N,1000))
    for i in range(N):
        Signals[i,:] = np.random.rand(1000)
    Res = np.zeros(Signals.shape)
    for i in range(N):
        Res[i, :] = energy2(Signals[i, :], window,i)
    print(Res)
    # parallel
    cpu_nb = 11  # multiprocessin
    Res2 = np.zeros(Signals.shape)
    idx = 0
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_nb)
    args = []
    for h in range(N):
        args.append([window,Signals[h, :],h])
    A = pool.map(energy2, args)
    for imap in range(len(A)):
        Res2[imap, :] = A[imap]


    print(Res - Res2) #find same results
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to this lies in starmap. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments) for a previous solution. I'm not sure on the format of your inputs, but my guess is that you will need to zip them if you do indeed have a list of lists.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    # serial
    window = np.random.rand(32)
    N = 10
    Signals = np.zeros((N,1000))
    for i in range(N):
        Signals[i,:] = np.random.rand(1000)
    Res = np.zeros(Signals.shape)
    for i in range(N):
        Res[i, :] = energy2(Signals[i, :], window,i)
    print(Res)
    # parallel
    cpu_nb = 11  # multiprocessin
    Res2 = np.zeros(Signals.shape)
    idx = 0
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpu_nb)
    args = []
    for h in range(N):
        args.append([window,Signals[h, :],h])
    A = pool.starmap(energy2, args)
    for imap in range(len(A)):
        Res2[imap, :] = A[imap]


    print(Res - Res2) #find same results
```

Comment: that is an even better idea. +1

Answer (score 1):

That is a lot of code, but I think changing the `energy2` function to:

```
def energy2(items):
    signal, window, i = items
    ...
```

would do the trick. The problem seems to be that you are passing a list to a function that expects 3 values. Normally you can do this by using a *starred expression* but in your case it is a bit more delicate than that since you are using `map`.. So let the function handle its input.